# Can't Listen To Notifications with Laravel Echo

Tags: laravel, real-time, laravel-echo

I am building a website with real-time notifications. But I can't listen to notifications with Laravel Echo. I couldn't understand why it doesn't work.

Listening

```
this.$echo.private('App.User.' + this.user.id)
    .notification(notification => {
        console.log(notification);
    });
```

Notifying:

```
user->notify(new \App\Notifications\SomeoneRepliedYourPikir([
        'pikir_id' => request()->get('pikir_id'),
        'username' => request()->user()->username
    ]));
```

Channels:

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

I think I pasted all necessary stuff to understand my situation. Other things are working fine, like presence channels.

My Laravel-echo-server.json

```
{
"authHost": "http://pikirler.dev",
"authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
"clients": [
    {
        "appId": "2051a3c22fdd8a43",
        "key": "500c9e2934af4f6e93892f56abfcdc27"
    }
],
"database": "redis",
"databaseConfig": {
    "redis": {
        "port": "6379",
        "host": "127.0.0.1"
    },
    "sqlite": {
        "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
    }
},
"devMode": true,
"host": "pikirler.dev",
"port": "6001",
"protocol": "http",
"socketio": {},
"sslCertPath": "",
"sslKeyPath": ""}
```

Comment: Can we see your laravel-echo-server.json?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy it is joining the channel and it is successfully firing event BroadcastNotificationCreated, but in console there is anything

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Ohh I found my silly mistake. My mistake is I moved all my Models into Models directory and didn't change in channels.php. Silly mistake took me hours to solve :D

Comment: Yup, that's a very common mistake! Glad you got it solved.

Comment: Can I see you channels.php file? Can't change name space. I also changed my models directory and notifications stopped working

Answer (score -1):

Put this function in your User model.It will work fine

```
public function receivesBroadcastNotificationsOn()
    {
        return 'App.User.'.$this->id;
    }
```